# How to prevent preservation of aspect ratio in svg.js

Tags: html, svg, svg.js

I am trying to render a rectangle with svg.js (https://svgjs.dev) and NOT preserve the aspect ratio when the parent/window is resized. It works fine for a plain svg element but not for the svg.js elements:

https://jsfiddle.net/h8sgown7/3/

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/svg.js/2.6.4/svg.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
        SVG.on(document, 'DOMContentLoaded', function() {
 
    var draw = SVG('drawing')
    var rect = draw.rect(300, 50).move(0, 0).fill('#ff0000');
        draw.viewbox(0, 0, 300, 55);
    draw.attr('preserveAspectRatio', 'none');
    })
  </script>

  <title>SVGTest</title>
  <style>
    .drawing 
    {
      width: 100%;
      height:50px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="drawing"></div>
  <svg width="100%" height="100px" viewbox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">
    <rect width="100" height="100" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255)" />
  </svg>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set the height to `100px` in your plain svg element. By default the svg is set to `width="100%" height="100%"` by svg.js.

Just change your svg.js generated svg height to match your inline svg.

```
draw.viewbox(0, 0, 300, 55).height('100px');
```

https://jsfiddle.net/h8sgown7/7/